# How do I draw a line that exits from the middle of a textbox in run time?

Tags: wpf

A picture is worth a thousand words - so here is the existing against the desirable:

[image]

This is what I've tried w/o success:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
        txt.Text = "asdsahd sakh uj";
        txt.Background = Brushes.LightBlue;
        Canvas.SetLeft(txt, 100);
        container.Children.Add(txt);


        Line line = new Line();
        line.SetBinding(Line.X1Property, new Binding("Canvas.Left") {ElementName = "txt"});
        line.X2 = line.X1;
        line.Y1 = 0;
        line.Y2 = 100;
        line.StrokeThickness = 2;
        container.Children.Add(line);
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure the setting TxtBlock txt - new TextBlock() gives it an ElementName.  Look as setting the ElementName explicitly.

Comment: Thanks BalamBalam, tried it, didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the solution below, I assume that your `Canvas` has a height and width that can change at runtime, and that your `TextBlock` can also have a height and width that change dynamically as well. The approach looks complicated, but its not. Of course doing this in XAML would be much, much more readable:

1. Create a `TextBlock` add to canvas.
2. Create a `Line` add to canvas.
3. Use a `MultiBinding` to compute the `Canvas.Left` property for the `TextBlock`. If either the width of the `Canvas` or the `TextBlock` changes, this binding will re-evaluate and the `IMultiValueConverter` will provide a new value. The value of `Canvas.Left` for the `TextBlock` should be: `Canvas.ActualWidth/2` - `TextBlock.ActualWidth/2`.
4. To the same as in step 3, but this time for the `Line`.
5. Use a `MultiBinding` to compute the `Line.Y2` property for the `Line`. Assuming you want to draw the line to the bottom edge of the `Canvas`. To compute this: `Canvas.ActualHeight` - `TextBlock.ActualHeight`. The binding will re-evaluate if either change and the `IMultiValueConverter` will provide a new value.
6. Use a `Binding` to set the `Canvas.Top` property on the `Line`. In this example, the `Line` is drawn immediately below the `TextBlock`, so we can just bind to `TextBlock.ActualHeight`.

**TextBlock and Line Creation**

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create TextBlock and Line
        var textBlock = new TextBlock {Text = "123456"};
        var line = new Line { StrokeThickness = 2, Stroke = new SolidColorBrush { Color = Colors.Black }, Y1 = 0 };
        myCanvas.Children.Add(textBlock);
        myCanvas.Children.Add(line);

        // Setup bindings
        InitializeTextBlockCanvasLeftBinding(myCanvas, textBlock);
        InitializeLineCanvasLeftBinding(myCanvas, line);
        InitializeLineY2Binding(myCanvas, textBlock, line);
        InitializeLineCanvasTopBinding(myCanvas, textBlock, line);
    }

    private void InitializeLineCanvasTopBinding(Canvas canvas, TextBlock textBlock, Line line)
    {
        var textBlockActualHeightBinding = new Binding
        {
            Source = textBlock,
            Path = new PropertyPath("ActualHeight"),
        };

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Canvas.TopProperty, textBlockActualHeightBinding);
    }

    private void InitializeLineY2Binding(Canvas canvas, TextBlock textBlock, Line line)
    {
        var canvasActualHeightBinding = new Binding
        {
            Source = myCanvas,
            Path = new PropertyPath("ActualHeight"),
        };

        var textBlockActualHeightBinding = new Binding
        {
            Source = textBlock,
            Path = new PropertyPath("ActualHeight"),
        };

        var lineY2MultiBinding = new MultiBinding { Converter = new LineY1MultiConverter() };
        lineY2MultiBinding.Bindings.Add(textBlockActualHeightBinding);
        lineY2MultiBinding.Bindings.Add(canvasActualHeightBinding);

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Line.Y2Property, lineY2MultiBinding);
    }

    private void InitializeLineCanvasLeftBinding(Canvas canvas, Line line)
    {
        var lineActualWidthBinding = new Binding
        {
            Source = line,
            Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth"),
        };

        var canvasActualWidthBinding = new Binding
        {
            Source = myCanvas,
            Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth"),
        };

        var lineLeftMultiBinding = new MultiBinding { Converter = new CanvasLeftCenterMultiConverter() };
        lineLeftMultiBinding.Bindings.Add(lineActualWidthBinding);
        lineLeftMultiBinding.Bindings.Add(canvasActualWidthBinding);

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Canvas.LeftProperty, lineLeftMultiBinding);
    }

    private void InitializeTextBlockCanvasLeftBinding(Canvas canvas, TextBlock textBlock)
    {
        var textBlockActualWidthBinding = new Binding
        {
            Source = textBlock,
            Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth"),
        };

        var canvasActualWidthBinding = new Binding
        {
            Source = myCanvas,
            Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth"),
        };

        var textBlockLeftMultiBinding = new MultiBinding { Converter = new CanvasLeftCenterMultiConverter() };
        textBlockLeftMultiBinding.Bindings.Add(textBlockActualWidthBinding);
        textBlockLeftMultiBinding.Bindings.Add(canvasActualWidthBinding);

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(textBlock, Canvas.LeftProperty, textBlockLeftMultiBinding);
    }
```

**MultiConverter to compute the length of the line**

```
public class LineY1MultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values != null && values.Length == 2 && values[0] is double && values[1] is double)
        {
            var canvasHeight = (double)values[1];
            var textBlockHeight = (double) values[0];
            return canvasHeight - textBlockHeight;
        }

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**MultiConverter to center elements horizontally on the Canvas**

```
public class CanvasLeftCenterMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values != null && values.Length == 2 && values[0] is double && values[1] is double)
        {
            var canvasMiddle = (double)values[1]/2;
            var elementHalf = (double) values[0]/2;
            return canvasMiddle - elementHalf;
        }

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

To make the above code more clear - it really is just a 1-to-1 translation of the following XAML (using the `MultiValueConverters` from above):

```
    <Canvas x:Name="myCanvas" Background="Pink">
        <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="1234567890">
            <Canvas.Left>
                 <MultiBinding Converter="{l:CanvasLeftCenterMultiConverter}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" Path="ActualWidth" />
                    <Binding ElementName="myCanvas" Path="ActualWidth" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Canvas.Left>
        </TextBlock>
        <Line StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="{Binding ElementName=myTextBlock, Path=ActualHeight}" Y1="0">
            <Line.Y2>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{l:LineY1MultiConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="myTextBlock" Path="ActualHeight" />
                    <Binding ElementName="myCanvas" Path="ActualHeight" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Line.Y2>
            <Canvas.Left>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{l:CanvasLeftCenterMultiConverter}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" Path="ActualWidth" />
                    <Binding ElementName="myCanvas" Path="ActualWidth" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Canvas.Left>
        </Line>
    </Canvas>
```

As you can see - if the canvas size changes, the text size changes, or the line thickness changes, the bindings ensure new values for `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` are computed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it's so long so I didn't tried it yet, but I guess it's enough and even more... thanks